# Google + Signin Authentication Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, google-plus, single-sign-on

I want to implement something as shown in this website.

http://www.beabigrockstar.com/guides/aspnet-mvc-google-plus-login/

But I do not want to upgrade from .Net Framework 4.0 to .Net Framework 4.5

is this possible by any other approach

I am currently using OAuth 1.0 but we need to migrate to google plus signin 
because Google is depreciating oAuth 1.0 and gradually stop supporting this.
please read this one

https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oid2

Please let me know how to achieve the same within MVC for .Net Framework 4.0

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Have you tried following the guide anyways? I don't actually see it listing requirements anywhere.

Comment: abraham yes i tried following the guide but the Owin.Security.Providers Nuget package described here is not getting downloaded in .net framework 4.0 (i.e Visual studio 2010)